# Why do I keep coming up with an error at the end of my code?

Tags: python, function, return

So when inputting my third elif variable in my main function, my other functions don't work. My question, is what's stopping it. Lines 123, 124, 125, keep receiving the "UnboundLocalError: totalcost referenced before assignement"

`

```
def welcome():
    print("Hello and Welcome Super Maids")


def LC (a , b): 
    totalcost = 150 + a + (b * 10)
    print("The total of your service is:\n$",totalcost)
    return totalcost


def DC (a, b):
    totalcost = 300 + a + (b * 10)
    print("The total of your service is:\n$",totalcost)
    return totalcost


def SeniorDiscount(totalcost):
    ans = str(input("Are you by a chance a serior citizen? [y/n]"))
    if ans == 'y':
        age = eval(input("What year were you born? [XXXX]"))
        if age >= 1960:
            print("Perfect! Thank you, sir/ma'am!")
            discount = totalcost * .15
            print("Your discount is:\n$", discount)
            totalcost = totalcost - discount
            print("Great! The total cost of your serivce is:$",totalcost)
            return totalcost
    elif ans == 'n':
       print("Thank you for being honest!")
       print("Great! The total cost of your serivce is:$",totalcost)
       return totalcost
    else:
        print("We'll need an actual answer from you in order to continue")
        SeniorDiscount(totalcost)
        return totalcost

    
def YardService():
    shrubCost = 10
    edgingCost = 20
    sqftCost = 20
    sqrft = eval(input("What is the square footage of your yard?\n"))
    linsqft = eval(input("What is the linear square footage of your yard?\n"))
    shrubs = eval(input("How many shrubs do you have?\n"))
    totalcost = (shrubCost * shrubs)+(edgingCost + linsqft)+(sqftCost * sqrft)
    return totalcost


def YardService1():
    shrubCost = 10
    edgingCost = 20
    sqftCost = 20
    sqrft = eval(input("What is the square footage of your yard?\n"))
    linsqft = eval(input("What is the linear square footage of your yard?\n"))
    shrubs = eval(input("How many shrubs do you have?\n"))
    totalcost = (shrubCost * shrubs)+(edgingCost + linsqft)+(sqftCost * sqrft)
    return totalcost

        
def homeservice():
    welcome()
    NumberOfRooms = eval(input("How many rooms are in need of cleaning?\n"))
    if NumberOfRooms < 3:
        print("Your starting total is: $", 120)
        CostOfRooms = 120
        windows = eval(input("How many windows do you have in need of cleaning?\n"))
        CostOfWindows = 10
        TypeClean = eval(input("What kind of cleaning service are you in search of?\n1-Light Cleaning\n2-Deep Cleaning\n"))
        if TypeClean == 1:
            totalcost = LC(CostOfRooms,windows)
            return totalcost
        elif TypeClean == 2:
            totalcost = DC(CostOfRooms,windows)
            return totalcost
        else:
            print("You must select a service in order to continue")
    elif 2 < NumberOfRooms < 4:
        print("Your starting total is: $", 150)
        CostOfRooms = 150
        windows = eval(input("How many windows do you have in need of cleaning?\n"))
        CostOfWindows = 10
        TypeClean = eval(input("What kind of cleaning service are you in search of?\n1-Light Cleaning\n2-Deep Cleaning\n"))
        if TypeClean == 1:
            totalcost = LC(CostOfRooms,windows)
            return totalcost
        elif TypeClean == 2:
            totalcost = DC(CostOfRooms,windows)
            return totalcost
        else:
            print("You must select a service in order to continue")
    elif 3 < NumberOfRooms < 6:
        print("Your starting total is: $", 175)
        CostOfRooms = 175
        windows = eval(input("How many windows do you have in need of cleaning?\n"))
        CostOfWindows = 10
        TypeClean = eval(input("What kind of cleaning service are you in search of?\n1-Light Cleaning\n2-Deep Cleaning\n"))
        if TypeClean == 1:
            LC(CostOfRooms,windows)
            return totalcost
        elif TypeClean == 2:
            DC(CostOfRooms,windows)
            return totalcost
        else:
            print("You must select a service in order to continue")
    elif NumberOfRooms >= 6:
        print("We do not offer a service of this size")


def main():
    print("We'll start by asking you a set of questions")
    YHB = eval(input("What kind of cleaning service are you in search of?\n1-Home Serivce\n2-Yard Service\n3-Both\n"))
    if YHB == 1:
        totalcost = homeservice()
        SeniorDiscount(totalcost)
    elif YHB == 2:
        totalcost = YardService()
        SeniorDiscount(totalcost)
    elif YHB == 3:
        toatlcost = homeservice() + YardService()
        #print(totalcost)
        #YardService1(totalcost)
        SeniorDiscount(totalcost)
    else:
        print("You must have selected nothing, we'll try again.")
        main()


#--- Execute --------------------------------------------------------
main()
```

`

The process works when trying to do elif on 1 and 2, however it completely shuts down when attempting to work within the last version process.

Comment: Can you please expand on "completely shuts down" - what is your error/traceback?

Comment: for instance, on main, when it performs the if statement 1, it will be conduct homeservice() and then go into seniordiscount(totalcost). however, it will submit an error when going into elif 3. I apologize, for the miscommunication in stating it shuts down.

Comment: Side note, not sure where you might have seen `X = eval(input('...'))` but this this a terrible idea. Never use `eval` on user input. Use `X = int(input('...'))` if needed. `X = str(input('...'))` is however not needed, `input` always returns a string.

Comment: Rgr, understood. I can see why you say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `main()`:

```
elif YHB == 3:
        toatlcost = homeservice() + YardService()
```

You've misspelled "totalcost".

That's A bug at any rate. You also have some other issues that'll crop up under different cases - it's possible to call a number of your functions and return `None` for totalcost - which will trip you up when you later try to add that return to something. I suggest you ensure a return of something numeric - zero for want of anything better.

Comment: oh my god, I sincerely apologize for wasting everyone's time. Thank you

Comment: @CreatorCombat in the future, providing a copy/paste of the full error  traceback in question would make it clear which line had an error and exactly what the error was.

Comment: Ah.  You're totally correct.  How did I miss that one!  lol.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your code and I got an error on line 129 and 122 and I think I figured out what the error problem is.

I think you might have an error with not globalizing the variable so try doing:

```
global totalcost
```

for each of the variables or something like that. Good luck!

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, are you stating that line of code goes somewhere in my program?

Comment: From what I see, this won't help by itself.  There is no `totalcost` variable defined at the global level, so adding `global totalcost` will still result in an error.  Since this value is being set in the same function for other clauses of the same `if`, I assume that the OP means to set it to something inside that function before trying to return it.